# How can I activate button style with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

[Here's the code](http://jsfiddle.net/pnP4D/15/)

I want to activate a new button style

```
if (visited.length == 3) {
    **HERE**
    alert('You have reached the maximum rank 1 questions');
    return;
```

Basically, I want the button to grey out when visited.length == 3. How can I do this? I've already created the style, but I do not know CSS (yet) so I'm guessing I'm not naming it right.

```
.button:maxques {
    padding:4px 39px;
    border:solid 3px #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font:23px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ababab;
    background-color:#ededed;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#81898c', endColorstr='#81898c', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `**HERE**` by :

```
document.getElementById('your_button_id').className = 'button';
```

Comment: This is what i did. I also removed .button:, so my line was
`document.getElementById('btn').className = 'maxques';`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `button2` with the css of your new button

```
if (visited.length == 3) {
    document.getElementById('btn').className = 'button2';
    alert('You have reached the maximum rank 1 questions');
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something along these lines, though you'll need to adjust your CSS as the hover attribute still gets applied.

```
if (visited.length == 3) {
    if(this.className.indexOf("disabled") < 0) { // disabled hasn't been applied yet
       this.className += " disabled-button";
    } 
    alert('You have reached the maximum rank 1 questions');
    return;
}
```

Also, I wouldn't add a custom psuedo-class like you are doing.  In the above example, I changed your `button:maxques` to `.disabled-button`.

Here is a JsFiddle with a working CSS style and js approach.
http://jsfiddle.net/xDaevax/pnP4D/18/

Comment: I agree with this, I'd recommend no custom psuedo-class...a combo of this answer and @weeger's answer would be good, fiddle updated to show : http://jsfiddle.net/pnP4D/16/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable the button entirely,

```
if(visited.length==3) buttonObj.disabled = "true"
```

If you want to just have it become grey (assuming your CSS above is what you want for it to become) then I suggest

### CSS

```
button.maxques {
    padding:4px 39px;
    border:solid 3px #ffffff;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    -moz-border-radius:4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font:23px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#ababab;
    background-color:#ededed;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#81898c', endColorstr='#81898c', GradientType=0);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #81898c 100%);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 2px #bababa, inset 0px 0px 1px #ffffff;
}
```

### JavaScript

```
buttonObj = document.getElementById("button");
if(visited.length==3) {
  buttonObj.className = (buttonObj.className!=null||buttonObj.className!=undefined) buttonObj.className + " maxques" : "maxques";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
buttonID = document.getElementById("btn");

    if(visited.length==3) 
      buttonID.css( "color", "grey" );
```

for your [reference](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value)
or

```
buttonID = document.getElementById("btn");
    
if(visited.length==3) 
 buttonID.addClass( "myClass yourClass" )
```

for your [reference](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

Comment: This doesn't run for me.  The document.getElementById("btn") will not return a JQuery object, so you won't be able to use the css or addClass methods.  Also, OP did not specify JQuery in their question.